# Redirect to HTTPS only if a certificate is installed

Tags: asp.net, ssl, redirect, iis, webforms

Is there a way, in ASP.NET WebForms, to perform an always try redirect from HTTP to HTTPS? So, if the installation has a valid certificate installed, requests to HTTP URLs will always redirect to HTTPS. However, if the installation does not have a certificate installed, do not redirect and allow access over HTTP.

What we are trying to avoid is having to adjust an install-specific Boolean option saying whether or not each installation has a valid TLS certificate installed or not. We'd also like to do this in .NET rather than in IIS if possible. This application is hosted by users on a variety of environments, and we are trying to avoid them needing to do any custom configuration to enable this redirect themselves.

Comment: Why not explore any option to redirect from DNS level ?

Comment: Thanks, @ABDmaverick, but that would require install-specific modification as well. The application is self-hosted by users, and we are trying to avoid having to make individual modifications to the hosting environment and DNS configurations.

Comment: `the installation does not have a certificate installed` The certificate is installed in the server-side. Do you mean you want to know your server has a certificate installed?

Comment: @Win yes, essentially is there a way from .NET to do a self-check to see if it has a certificate and can be served encrypted. If so, redirect. If not, continue serving the HTTP request.

Comment: There is something like Request.IsLocal to check ssl. Need to check this . I will get back with more info

Comment: Since we were not able to figure out a solution for this, we ended up adding a default false option in the application that users can turn on to enable the redirection. I hate defaulting to insecure, but not every user has a certificate, so it is the way we have to proceed for now. Thanks, all, for your help.